# Set cursor position to end of line in text area (HTML, js)

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Is there a way to set the position of the cursor to the end of a specific line (more precisely the first line) in a HTML text area with javascript. The text area contains a text with unknown length, but there is at least one line. The length of the first line is also unknown.

I am working with jQuery.

Comment: Yeah the thing is, I do not know the exact position of the cursor. I want to put it to the end of a line, but I don't know how many characters the line has.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what kind of textarea is that? What are you trying to achieve? I mean... why exactly at the end of the first (or any) line?

Comment: It is a simple HTML textarea (<textarea></textarea>) with content. And for the why: Why not? This is the behaviour I want to achive. Does it really matter?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I use along side jQuery.

```
$.fn.cursorToEnd = function() {
    var start, end;
    start = end = this.val().length;
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
```

To use on textbox with id = "InputBox" :

```
$('#InputBox').cursorToEnd();
```